# how to use a list to find the bigger than values within that list python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to use a csv list that is saved through code to compare the values within that list with the next value in the list and to get the printed out come of 1 if it is bigger and 0 if it is smaller.

here is the code I'm dealing with:

```
with dta:
    writer = csv.writer(dta)
    writer.writerow(inner)
print(inner)

df = pd.read_csv('dta.csv')
h111 = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
print(h111)
```

these are the results i get:

```
[['2', '1', ',', '5', '6', '9', '.', '6.1', '3'], ['2', '1', ',', 5.0, 6.0, 9.0, '.', 6.0, 3.0], ['1', '8', ',', 9.0, 5.0, 2.0, '.', 9.0, 2.0], ['-', '-', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], ['1', '8', ',', 9.0, 4.0, 4.0, '.', 3.0, 6.0], ['1', '8', ',', 9.0, 4.0, 4.0, '.', 3.0, 6.0], ['1', '8', ',', 9.0, 4.0, 4.0, '.', 3.0, 6.0], ['1', '8', ',', 9.0, 4.0, 4.0, '.', 3.0, 6.0], ['-', '-', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], ['1', '8', ',', 9.0, 4.0, 4.0, '.', 3.0, 6.0], ['-', '-', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], ['2', '0', ',', 1.0, 5.0, 0.0, '.', 5.0, 3.0], ['2', '0', ',', 1.0, 5.0, 0.0, '.', 5.0, 3.0], ['2', '0', ',', 1.0, 5.0, 0.0, '.', 5.0, 3.0], ['2', '0', ',', 1.0, 5.0, 0.0, '.', 5.0, 3.0], ['2', '0', ',', 1.0, 6.0, 0.0, '.', 8.0, 6.0], ['2', '0', ',', 1.0, 8.0, 2.0, '.', 5.0, 9.0], ['2', '0', ',', 1.0, 7.0, 8.0, '.', 0.0, 4.0], ['2', '0', ',', 0.0, 6.0, 8.0, '.', 3.0, 2.0], ['2', '0', ',', 0.0, 5.0, 6.0, '.', 8.0, 6.0], ['2', '0', ',', 0.0, 5.0, 6.0, '.', 8.0, 6.0], ['2', '0', ',', 0.0, 5.0, 6.0, '.', 8.0, 6.0], ['2', '0', ',', 0.0, 5.0, 6.0, '.', 8.0, 6.0], ['2', '0', ',', 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, '.', 2.0, 1.0], ['2', '0', ',', 0.0, 3.0, 7.0, '.', 8.0, 2.0], ['1', '9', ',', 9.0, 6.0, 8.0, '.', 9.0, 6.0], ['1', '9', ',', 8.0, 4.0, 6.0, '.', 7.0, 0.0], ['1', '9', ',', 8.0, 4.0, 1.0, '.', 8.0, 0.0], ['-', '-', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], ['1', '9', ',', 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, '.', 8.0, 4.0], ['1', '8', ',', 9.0, 1.0, 2.0, '.', 4.0, 4.0], ['1', '8', ',', 9.0, 1.0, 2.0, '.', 4.0, 4.0], ['1', '8', ',', 8.0, 8.0, 6.0, '.', 6.0, 2.0], ['1', '8', ',', 8.0, 8.0, 6.0, '.', 6.0, 2.0], ['1', '8', ',', 8.0, 4.0, 7.0, '.', 5.0, 6.0], ['-', '-', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], ['1', '8', ',', 9.0, 9.0, 1.0, '.', 2.0, 2.0], ['1', '9', ',', 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, '.', 3.0, 3.0], ['-', '-', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], ['-', '-', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], ['-', '-', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], ['-', '-', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], ['1', '9', ',', 0.0, 4.0, 4.0, '.', 1.0, 0.0], ['-', '-', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], ['5', '.', '4', 0.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], ['-', '-', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]]
```

so now if you would kindly assist me in finding a way to perform the act of comparing the values in the csv list with the value next in line.

Answer (score 1):

Because your data contains non-numeric values it is not possible to compare every value.

```py
def compare_line(line):
    compare = range(0, len(line) - 1, 2)
    for idx in compare:
        try:
            greater = float(line[idx]) > float(line[idx + 1])
        
        except ValueError: # cannot compare
            yield None # you could also use 0 instead of None which would be less verbose
            continue
        
        yield 1 if greater else 0
```

The function above takes all entries pairwise of a row and checks if the left one is greater than the right one for each pair and yields

- `1` if left value is greater
- `0` if left value is less
- `None` if it is not possible to compare the values

Calling the function will return a generator object that you can iterate through. To print the result, we can use a list comprehension:

```py
for row in h111:
    print([i for i in compare_line(row)])
```